# XIB popover display

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uipopovercontroller, popover

I seem to be having trouble making a popover xib display when app is loaded. Here is what I have in the ViewDidLoad.I am sorry, I am new to this was looking into tutorials and ran into a problem where the app crashes. The error log is "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSException', reason:
'Could not load NIB in bundle:" "(loaded)' with name 'search''

```
     ViewController* viewController2 = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"search" bundle:nil];
self.popOverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:viewController2];

_popOverController.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(350,100);
```

Comment: And what exactly is your problem?

Comment: This code just creates the popover, it doesn't show it. How are you trying to show it? Also, you have iPhone in your tags -- are you trying to do this on an iPhone? Popovers are for iPad only.

Comment: Sorry, edited my question. Basically my goal is to make an xib by the name of "search" to appear as a popover.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7765213/ios5-could-not-load-nib-in-bundle).

It says that your nib 'search' does not exist in the builded app. Either your xib is not named "search.xib" or your xib is not included into your project. YOu can check this by looking into the .app-directory on your phone or simulator.

Answer (score 1):

You need to present it somehow. The code you show just creates the popover. You need to use either presentPopoverFromRect:inView:permittedArrowDirections:animated: or presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:permittedArrowDirections:animated: to actually show it.